# Optimizing MySQL queries/database

Tags: mysql

I have two tables TABLE A and TABLE B.
TABLE A contain 1 million (1,000,000) records and 4 fields while TABLE 2 contain 60,000 and 3 fields.
I am running a query which joins these two tables and usees WHERE clause to find specific products like WHERE product like '%Bags%' and product like 'Bags%' e.t.c.

When I run the query directly in phpMyAdmin then it returns records in around 1 or 2 seconds. But when they are being used on website, they are sometime taking 9 or 10 seconds according to MySQL 'slow query' log. Actually my website response was very slow at times so upon investigation I found out it is due to MySQL as I came to know about 'slow query log'.

The slow query log consists of all SQL statements that took more than long_query_time seconds to execute and required at least min_examined_row_limit rows to be examined.

So according to that log "query_time" for above query was 13 seconds while in some cases they even had "query_time" exceeding 50 seconds.

Both my tables are using PRIMARY keys as well as INDEXES. So I want to know how can I optimize them more or is there any way I can optimize MySQL settings in general?

This slowness of website doesn't happen all the time but sometimes (may be once in a week) and lasts for around 1 or 2 minutes. It gets decent amount of traffic and there are many other queries too, the above I posted was just one example.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all things MySQL and performance related, check out http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/

Check your queries with EXPLAIN, see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-explain.html) and [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/06/15/explain-extended-can-tell-you-all-kinds-of-interesting-things/) for info on how to use EXPLAIN as query diagnostic tool.

It's not enough to just have indexes. Are you indexing the fields searched in the WHERE clause? Also do you have indexes for the fields used in the WHERE clause (including the fields you mention in ORDER BY, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses as well as JOINs)? If you have grouped fields in a single index, that index won't be hit unless you have a query that searches all those fields together. If you group fields in an index make sure they the index will actually be used in your query (EXPLAIN is your friend).

That said, it could be many other things as well: poorly configured MySQL server, poorly tuned server, bad schema. But your queries and your indexes are good place to start your investigation.

[Here](http://joinfu.com/presentations/kill-mysql-performance.pdf) is a nice summary of performance best practices from Jay Pipes of MySQL.

Comment: Also, as other people have alluded, your performance will vary based on the traffic of your site. If you're running the query in phpMyAdmin during off peak hours you'll obviously get better performance than if you (or a visitor) is running the query during your peak traffic times.

Answer (score 1):

`like '%Bags%'` query cannot be optimized using indexes.

The only way to improve performance here is to use [fulltext indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) or get [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) to search.

Comment: @Ali: then why don't you search using `MATCH ... AGAINST`?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of some other queries are run at the time when you are going to refresh the page of your website. so if for example your website going to run 8-10 queries at time of page refresh then it will take some more time than you run single query in `phpmyadmin`. and if its take 1-1.5 min to execute then its may not the query problem but it may have prob with the server speed also.

and you also can use `MATCH() AGAINST()` statement for optimize this type of search queries.

Otherwise you are already using `PRIMARY KEY, INDEXES and JOINS` so there is no need to worry about other things.

just check it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to optimize Databases and queries. My method is the following.

> **Look at the DB Schema and see if it makes sense**

Most often, Databases have bad designs and are not normalized. This can greatly affect the speed of your Database. As a general case, learn the 3 Normal Forms and apply them at all times. The normal forms above 3rd Normal Form are often called de-normalization forms but what this really means is that they break some rules to make the Database faster.

What I suggest is to stick to the 3rd normal form except if you are a DBA (which means you know subsequent forms and know what you're doing). Normalization after the 3rd NF is often done at a later time, not during design.

> **Only query what you really need**

Filter as much as possible

Your Where Clause is the most important part for optimization.

> **Select only the fields you need**

Never use "Select *" -- Specify only the fields you need; it will be faster and will use less bandwidth.

> **Be careful with joins**

Joins are expensive in terms of time. Make sure that you use all the keys that relate the two tables together and don't join to unused tables -- always try to join on indexed fields. The join type is important as well (INNER, OUTER,... ).

> **Optimize queries and stored procedures (Most Run First)**

Queries are very fast. Generally, you can retrieve many records in less than a second, even with joins, sorting and calculations. As a rule of thumb, if your query is longer than a second, you can probably optimize it.

Start with the Queries that are most often used as well as the Queries that take the most time to execute.

> **Add, remove or modify indexes**

If your query does Full Table Scans, indexes and proper filtering can solve what is normally a very time-consuming process. All primary keys need indexes because they makes joins faster. This also means that all tables need a primary key. You can also add indexes on fields you often use for filtering in the Where Clauses.

You especially want to use Indexes on Integers, Booleans, and Numbers. On the other hand, you probably don't want to use indexes on Blobs, VarChars and Long Strings.

Be careful with adding indexes because they need to be maintained by the database. If you do many updates on that field, maintaining indexes might take more time than it saves.

In the Internet world, read-only tables are very common. When a table is read-only, you can add indexes with less negative impact because indexes don't need to be maintained (or only rarely need maintenance).

> **Move Queries to Stored Procedures (SP)**

Stored Procedures are usually better and faster than queries for the following reasons:

```
Stored Procedures are compiled (SQL Code is not), making them faster than SQL code.
SPs don't use as much bandwidth because you can do many queries in one SP. SPs also stay on the server until the final results are returned.
Stored Procedures are run on the server, which is typically faster.
Calculations in code (VB, Java, C++, ...) are not as fast as SP in most cases.
It keeps your DB access code separate from your presentation layer, which makes it easier to maintain (3 tiers model).
```

> **Remove unneeded Views**

Views are a special type of Query -- they are not tables. They are logical and not physical so every time you run select * from MyView, you run the query that makes the view and your query on the view.

If you always need the same information, views could be good.

If you have to filter the View, it's like running a query on a query -- it's slower.

> **Tune DB settings**

You can tune the DB in many ways. Update statistics used by the optimizer, run optimization options, make the DB read-only, etc... That takes a broader knowledge of the DB you work with and is mostly done by the DBA.

****> Using Query Analysers****

In many Databases, there is a tool for running and optimizing queries. SQL Server has a tool called the Query Analyser, which is very useful for optimizing. You can write queries, execute them and, more importantly, see the execution plan. You use the execution to understand what SQL Server does with your query.